# ¿Como añadir elementos a un array importado desde otra clase en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código que está subdividido en sus respectivas clases, hasta ahí todo bien. El problema es que, cuando yo cojo una variable llamémosla "listaDeCompra", de la clase "Compra" y la exporto para que pueda ser utilizada en varias clases, como por ejemplo "Cajero", si añado cosas en la ejecución del programa al array funciona correctamente pero el array me da un tamaño de 0 ¿por qué?
Mi código básicamente sería este: (todo esto es un ejemplo, no es real)

```javascript
class Compra {
  export [default] let listaDeCompra = [];

}
```

```javascript
import listaDeCompra from './compra.js';

class Humano {
   listaDeCompra[0] = "Pan";
   listaDeCompra[1] = "Jamón";
   listaDeCompra[2] = "Queso";
   console.log(listaDeCompra[0]); // Imprime "Pan".
   console.log(listaDeCompra[1]); // Imprime "Jamón".
   console.log(listaDeCompra[2]); // Imprime "Queso".
   console.log(listaDeCompra.length); //Imprime 0 
}
```

```javascript
import listaDeCompra from './compra.js';

class Cajero {
  console.log(listaDeCompra.length); // Imprime 0.
}
```

Lo más extraño es que no imprime algo como undefined o null sino que me imprime todos los detalles de lo que tiene el elemento del array en esa posición

¿Cómo podría hacer para tener un array al que se le puedan añadir y eliminar elementos desde cualquier clase?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que lo que tendrias que exportar es la clase, y como tal deberias instanciarla para poder usarla. De lo contrario poner el arreglo fuera de la clase y exportarlo desde ahi. Lo que supongo esta pasando, y digo supongo, es que estas creando un array cada vez, si no pones nada es como si pusieras var y realmente no estas usando el array original

Comment: ¿Puedes crear un [mcve]? Ese código que has puesto no compila y no puedo reproducir el comportamiento que dices tener

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un concepto un poco erroneo de lo que es una clase. Una clase es un molde para crear objetos. Por ejemplo puedes tener:

```js
class Compra{
  constructor(){
   this.listaCompras = [];
  }

  ingresar(compra){
   this.listaCompras.push(compra)
  }

  consultar(){
   return this.listaCompras;
  }
 } 

 const compraSandwich = new Compra();

 compraSandwich.ingresar("Pan")
 compraSandwich.ingresar("Jamón")
 compraSandwich.ingresar("Queso")
 console.log("Compra almacen: " + compraSandwich.consultar());
 
 const compraFruta = new Compra();
 
 compraFruta.ingresar("Pera");
 compraFruta.ingresar("Banana");
 compraFruta.ingresar("Manzana");
 console.log("Compra verdulería: " + compraFruta.consultar());
 
 //mas compras
 compraSandwich.ingresar("Gaseosa");
 console.log("Compra almacen: " + compraSandwich.consultar());
```

En este caso tienes una clase que genera listas de compras. Tiene un constructor que crea un array vacio (tambien se podria construir el array desde el constructor) y un metodo para llenar la lista con productos. Luego fuera de la clase creas objetos con new() cada objeto tendra su propia lista de compras y sera independiente uno del otro.
Si quieres usar esa clase desde otras clases tienes que heredarla, asi:

```js
class Compra{
  constructor(){
   this.listaCompras = [];
  }

  ingresar(compra){
   this.listaCompras.push(compra)
  }

  consultar(){
   return this.listaCompras;
  }
 } 

 const compraSandwich = new Compra();

 compraSandwich.ingresar("Pan")
 compraSandwich.ingresar("Jamón")
 compraSandwich.ingresar("Queso")
 console.log("Compra almacen: " + compraSandwich.consultar());
 
 const compraFruta = new Compra();
 
 compraFruta.ingresar("Pera");
 compraFruta.ingresar("Banana");
 compraFruta.ingresar("Manzana");
 console.log("Compra verdulería: " + compraFruta.consultar());
 
 //mas compras
 compraSandwich.ingresar("Gaseosa");
 console.log("Compra almacen: " + compraSandwich.consultar());

 //clase que hereda de compra
 class Persona extends Compra{
  constructor(nombre){
   super();
   this.nombre = nombre;
  }
 }

 const juan = new Persona("Juan");
 juan.ingresar("Tomate")
 juan.ingresar("Lechuga")
 console.log("Compra de Juan: " + juan.consultar())
```

De esta manera creas un objeto Persona que hereda los metodos de Compra y puedes usarlos para que esa persona tenga su lista de compras.

Ya si quieres usar la clase desde distintos modulos la exportas y puedes usarla.
Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias Hernán García, sí, me acabo de dar cuenta, qué bobo que soy jajajaja. ¡Me has iluminado!